# Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context - PHP, PDO, Sessions,

Tags: php, database, oop, session, pdo

I'm trying to modify a script that stores my session data in a database rather than the default but I'm having a bit of trouble as I keep getting the error above. It says I'm getting the error on lines 176 and 201.

Here is the function inside the sessionPdo class

```
public function _write($id, $sessionData)
{
    $session = $this->fetchSession($id); // line 176
    if( $session === false ) {
        $stmt = $this->db->prepare('INSERT INTO sessions (id, data, unixtime) VALUES (:id, :data, :time)');
    } else {
        $stmt = $this->db->prepare('UPDATE sessions SET data = :data, unixtime = :time WHERE id = :id');
    }
$stmt->execute( array(
        ':id' => $id,
        ':data' => $sessionData,
        ':time' => time()
    ));

if( $this->transaction ) {
    $this->db->commit();
}
}
```

And here is the fetchSession method in case it helps.

```
public function fetchSession($id)
{
    $stmt = $this->db->prepare('SELECT id, data FROM sessions WHERE id = :id AND unixtime > :unixtime');
    $stmt->execute( array(':id' => $id, ':unixtime' => ( time() - (int) ini_get('session.gc_maxlifetime') ) ) );
    $sessions = $stmt->fetchAll();

    if( $this->transaction ) {
        $this->db->commit();
}

    return empty($sessions) ? false : $sessions[0] ;
}
```

I've struggled to find what I'm doing wrong as all the solutions I've found are because the programmer tried to call $this from outside of the class. I'm new to PDO so thanks in advance for any help you can give.

Comment: The code itself looks fine. The problem is probably in whatever called `_write()` in the first place. If that code calls _write() outside of the object's scope, you'll get this errors as $this won't be defined inside _write() in that case.

Comment: Which lines are `176` and `201`?

Comment: It has nothing to do with PDO. You aren't by chance calling `_write()` statically anywhere? `sessionPdo::_write(.....)`? Try adding `print_r(debug_backtrace())` right before line 176 to see what's calling what.

Comment: @Jonathon Spooner - line 176 is commented on the third line of the first section of code. I haven't included line 201 as I figured I'd deal with one problem at a time and hoped that it would be the same solution.

Comment: @alexantd I've added what you suggested and it has returned this: Array ( [0] => Array ( [function] => _write [class] => we_sessionPdo [type] => :: [args] => Array ( [0] => 2b73efe7a6899da83ab0ad7ccb474560 [1] => access|i:1;currentURL|s:42:"http://localhost/music-phonebook/index.php";mpbat|i:594546384; ) ) ) which is just some session variables I'm storing as part of the script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, the problem is that you are calling `_write()` statically. You need to read up on the difference between static and instance methods. I apologize for not explaining it here but there are probably 5,000 people on SO alone who have run into the same problem, which is solved with about 15 minutes of applied reading.

When you're comfortable with that, research the Singleton and Factory patterns, which are two ways of providing access to object instances from a static context and are commonly applied in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling function `_write` statically, that means somewhere in your code you can find:

```
sessionPdo::_write($id, $sessionData);
```

What you have to do is to create object of sessionPdo class and then run this function on this object, ie:

```
$sessObj = new sessionPdo();
$sessObj->_write($id, $sessionData);
```

Comment: Also, if he had full error reporting, he would have seen an earlier warning, eg: `Strict Standards: Non-static method sessionPdo::_write() should not be called statically in /code/abc.php on line 999`

Comment: I haven't actually used that code, according to the source of the script I'm modifying, the way I actually use $_SESSION variables shouldn't change and all I needed to do was include the script, however, when I' have I've been faced with these errors. I'll investigate and add more details if I can find what you're talking about.

Comment: Though I've already including the first part of your suggestion creating an instance of the object. I was having a simliar problem at an earlier stage where I couldn't link to my database. I solved this by creating the instance of the PDO and passing it as a variable to my controller and on to my model. Will I also need to do the same with my $session PDO?

Comment: What I know for sure is that you need to read something about OOP in PHP (and OOP in general), try some examples, get accustomed to Singelton/Factory/Dependency Injection/Observer pattern and then decide what fits best into your application.